# Capture multiple camera in sync

Tags: video, ffmpeg, sync, webcam

How can I capture multiple webcam stream synchronized?
I tried using FFMPEG, mapping the outputs to different files in the same command line, but this resulted in 2 un-synchronized videos never the less, with different lengths even.

(I stumbled upon a similar question with IP cameras, but mine aren't overIP so the delay is caused for different reason.)

command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_5986&pid_111c&mi_00#6&104790c2&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global" -f dshow -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_5986&pid_111c&mi_00#6&104790c2&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global" -map 0 -vcodec copy out2.mp4 -map 1 -vcodec copy out1.mp4
```

Comment: If you are going to edit it afterwards I don't think sync. would be a problem, but how does your recording framework look like? what commands did you use?

Comment: I'm going to record a lot of videos and show them next to each other. I tried showing my videos, but whenever some movement was made it was horrible - the movement was made with different timing in each video...

(I edit the original message and added the ffmpeg command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after working with it for a few days, I found a solution:
Apparently when using `-f dshow`, this allocate a real time buffer.
While this buffer allow you to encode the video with higher resolution, this stop the video synchronization to real time because they are being read from a buffer that does not contain any time-stamp.

Instead, allocate a smaller real time buffer which will force ffmpeg to drop frames if it's not near real time.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 1M -r 30 -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_075d&mi_00#6&eb52b6a&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global" -f dshow -rtbufsize 1M -r 30 -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_075d&mi_00#8&46f2efb&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global" -framerate 30 -map 0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y C:\1\output1_1.mp4 -framerate 30 -map 1 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y C:\1\output2_1.mp4
```